# <img> with mjpeg-stream created with JS don't work fine in Firefox and Opera

Tags: html, image, video-streaming, mjpeg

I have an MJPEG which streams on a web-page using an `<img/>` tag. The stream can sometimes fall down for some time, and then start working again later. I check the status of the stream using AJAX.

When the stream is down, I change the picture in the `<img/>` tag to some placeholder. When the stream is online again, I remove the placeholder to show the stream. I do this by replacing the tags with:

```
$('#xxx').html()
```

In Chrome this works fine, and after re-connection, the animation goes on fine. In Opera and Firefox however, after the stream goes back online, it will only show me a single static frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be fixed with using
`<iframe src='path_to_mjpeg'>`
instead of
`<img src='path_to_mjpeg'>`
Chrome and Opera handle its creation with JS correctly.
Firefox starts playing successfully to, but with huge memory leak.

Comment: but be careful - mjpeg in iframe cause huge memory leak in Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=858615

Comment: Do you still need checking for broken connections when using iframe? If yes, can you show the part of the code how you do it?